# If $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> If $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

Here, a set of formulas is inconsistent means they syntactically imply some formula as well as its negation. Syntactic implication here consists of (1) given formulas, (2) all first-order logical axioms, (3) modus ponens.

I have tried to explicitly construct a syntactic proof for the conclusion but failed to come up with one.

Comment: Can you say more about how you've tried to construct the syntactic proof?

Comment: For instance, my progress includes showing $\Gamma \vdash \neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi$, and $\Gamma \vdash \neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi$ for some formula $\psi$. But I don't see how to make $\neg \varphi$ disappear and/or tie it to the conclusion. Also, I can prove $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg \varphi \} \vdash \varphi$, but this proof sequence may make use of $\neg \varphi$ somewhere.

Comment: In any case, you've proved that $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \phi \to (\theta \land \lnot \theta)$. So $\Gamma$ will also prove the contrapositive of that conclusion; try writing out the contrapositive.

Comment: Interesting, I thought one was "varphi" and the other was "phi". Anyway, I edited one of the symbols.

Comment: In Latex, they are "varphi" and "phi", but that's somewhat analogous to the difference between an italic "$a$" and an upright "a" - it is jarring to see them used to mean different things in the same equation.  Try the contrapositive thing I mentioned, and see if you can get that. If so, the way this site works, you'd be welcome to write it up an an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

You need the axiom (or *tautology*) :

> $\vdash (¬φ→¬ψ)→((¬φ→ψ)→φ)$.

Having already proved :

> if $Γ∪{¬φ}$ is *inconsistent*, then $Γ⊢¬φ→ψ$ and $Γ⊢¬φ→¬ψ$,

it is enough to aplly *modus ponens* twice to conclude with :

> > $Γ⊢φ$.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\alpha\}$ is inconsistent.  Then for some $\beta$ we have $\Gamma\vdash\beta$ and $\Gamma\vdash\neg\beta$.  It remains only to show that $\{\beta,\neg\beta\}\vdash\alpha$.

Comment: This was already mentioned in the comments. But also in the second sentence the $\Gamma$ should be $\Gamma + \lnot \alpha$; $\Gamma$ may be consistent.