# I’m doing an introduction to propositional logic course and am stuck on finding a proof for that s statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\Sigma \subseteq L$. Suppose $\Sigma$ is truth-consistent. Show that there exists a set $\Gamma \subseteq L$ such that $\Gamma$ is truth-consistent, $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma$ and, for all $Q \in L$, $\Gamma \models Q$ or $\Gamma \models \neg Q$.

How do you prove this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math StackExchange! Just a quick tip: you can use LaTeX on this site, see [MathJax help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also it helps to give a more descriptive title of the problem, and to indicate what you have tried so far. This allows us to give you better answers, while it also shows that you have made genuine effort yourself.

Comment: What is $L$? What does it mean to say that a set is truth-consistent?

Comment: See [Maximally consistent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624406/verification-of-lindenbaums-lemma-proof-for-the-mendelson-system-and-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by truth-consistent you simply mean consistent: that is, for no formula $\varphi$ one has both $\Sigma\vDash\varphi$ and $\Sigma\vDash\neg\varphi$. Then, as Mauro ALLEGRANZA mentions in a comment, this is the existence of a maximally consistent set of formulas.

You define $\Gamma$ by transfinite induction: assume $\{\varphi_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an enumeration of $L$ (you usually assume the number of connectives and propositional variables is at most enumerable, so this is a reasonable request). Then:

- define $\Gamma_{0}=\Sigma$;
- if $\Gamma_{n}\cup \{\varphi_{n}\}$ is consistent, define $\Gamma_{n+1}=\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$; if the union is inconsistent, then define $\Gamma_{n+1}=\Gamma_{n}$.

Notice, and this is very important, that $\Gamma_{n}$ is always consistent: $\Gamma_{0}$ is consistent, and if $\Gamma_{n}$ is consistent, either $\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$ is consistent and thus so is $\Gamma_{n+1}=\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$; or $\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$ is inconsistent, $\Gamma_{n+1}=\Gamma_{n}$ is consistent given our induction hypothesis.

We finally define $\Gamma=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Gamma_{n}$: it certainly satisfies $\Sigma=\Gamma_{0}\subseteq \Gamma$. We see that $\Gamma$ is consistent by compactness: suppose, otherwise, that $\Gamma\vDash \varphi$ and $\Gamma\vDash \neg\varphi$; by the compactness theorem, there exist $\alpha_{1}, ... , \alpha_{n}, \beta_{1}, ... , \beta_{m}\in \Gamma$ such that
$$\alpha_{1}, ... , \alpha_{n}\vDash\varphi\quad\text{and}\quad\beta_{1}, ... , \beta_{m}\vDash\neg\varphi.$$
Since $\{\varphi_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an enumeration of $L$, there exist $i_{1}, ... , i_{n}, j_{1}, ... , j_{m}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_{1}=\varphi_{i_{1}}, ... , \alpha_{n}=\varphi_{i_{n}}, \beta_{1}=\varphi_{j_{1}}, ... , \beta_{m}=\varphi_{j_{m}}$, and by taking $N=\max\{i_{1}, ... , i_{n}, j_{1}, ... , j_{m}\}$, you can see that $\alpha_{1}, ... , \alpha_{n}, \beta_{1}, ... , \beta_{m}\in \Gamma_{N}$, what implies $\Gamma_{N}\vDash\varphi$ and $\Gamma_{N}\vDash\neg\varphi$, contradicting the aforementioned result that all $\Gamma_{n}$ are consistent! $\Gamma$ must then be also consistent.

The final step is proving $\Gamma$ is maximal, meaning that, for any formula $\psi\notin \Gamma$, $\Gamma\cup\{\psi\}$ is inconsistent. Since $\{\varphi_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an enumeration of $L$, there must exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi_{n}=\psi$; now, $\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$ must be inconsistent, since otherwise we would have $\varphi_{n}\in \Gamma_{n+1}\subseteq \Gamma$, and therefore $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}\supseteq\Gamma_{n}\cup\{\varphi_{n}\}$ must also be inconsistent. So, for any formula $\psi$, if one has $\Gamma\not\vDash\psi$ and $\Gamma\not\vDash\neg\psi$, $\psi, \neg\psi\notin\Gamma$, and so both $\Gamma\cup\{\psi\}$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ are inconsistent, and therefore $\Gamma\cup\{\psi\vee\neg\psi\}$ is inconsistent, what is absurd given $\Gamma$ is consistent and $\psi\vee\neg\psi$ is an axiom.