# Can I show that the extension of a theory is consistent if we assume the original theory is consistent

Tags: logic

Let’s say I have some formal theory $T$, and I have a statement $A$. Let $L$ be an extension of $T$ s.t.
$$
L = T \cup \{A\}
$$
If we show that $T$ is consistent, can we show that $L$ is consistent so long as
$$
T \not\vdash \lnot A 
$$
That is, say if we assume that $T$ is consistent, and we have some model of $T$ where $A$ is true, does this necessarily imply the consistency of $L$ given that $T$ is consistent by assumption?

Comment: Yes; we have that if $Γ \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $Γ \vdash \lnot \varphi$. And thus, if $Γ \nvdash \lnot \varphi$, then $Γ \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is consistent.

Comment: And from a semantical point of view, consistent means *satisfiable*; thus, if we have a model $M$ satisfying $T$ and we have that $A$ is true in $M$, then this shows that $T \cup \{ A \}$ is satisfiable.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622847/proving-that-if-gamma-cup-gamma-is-inconsistent-then-gamma-vdash-ne)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this follows from the deduction theorem. The following version of the theorem is excerpted from Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic* (with notations changed to fit the question):

> Let $A$ be a statement. For every formula $B$ of $T$, $T \vdash A \to B$ iff $B$ is a theorem of $T \cup \{A\}$.

If $L$ is inconsistent, then $\perp$ is a theorem of $T \cup \{A\}$, so $T \vdash A \to \perp$, iff $T \vdash \neg A \;\vee \perp$, iff $T \vdash \neg A$.