# How can I prove it is inconsistent like this?

Tags: logic

I can't understand what the professor has taught so I don't know how to solve this problem.
Let $\mathcal L$ be a language, $\Gamma$ be a finite $\mathcal L$-theory and $\varphi$ be an $\mathcal L$-sentence. Show the following.
$\Gamma,\varphi$ is inconsistent if and only if $\Gamma \vdash\lnot\varphi$.
Would you please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. It’s really hard to meaningfully answer questions like this because it lacks any context to what you know. Please edit the OP with a description of what you know and an attempt to solve the problem. That’ll allow other users to better communicate with you.

Comment: You can see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622847/proving-that-if-gamma-cup-gamma-is-inconsistent-then-gamma-vdash-ne) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018833/if-gamma-cup-neg-varphi-is-inconsistent-then-gamma-vdash-varphi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

We have to start from the definition of *inconsistent* set of formulas: $Γ$ is inconsistent iff $Γ ⊢ \varphi$ and $Γ ⊢ ¬ \varphi$, for some formula $\varphi$.

For the "simple" part: if $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$, then also $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

But obviously $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \varphi$, and thus $\Gamma, \varphi$ is *inconsistent*.

For the othe part: if $\Gamma, \varphi$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \lnot \psi$ and $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \lnot \psi$, for some $\psi$.

Apply [Negation Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_introduction) rule to conclude with: $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.